# Filter an array of objects by a value from an array of different objects in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I reasonably new to jQuery, and I have trouble finding this out. I've got two arrays.

```
var arrayCountries = [{ Code:'NL', Name:'Netherlands'}, { Code:'BE', Name:'Belgium'}, ...];
var arrayCustomers = [{ Code:'C001', Country: 'NL', Group: 'A'}, { Code:'C002', Country: 'BE', Group: 'B'}, ...];
```

And some code to filter data. When a user selects a value in a 'Group'select box I need to refresh two select boxes. The first array (customerData) is populated as expected. However I have no idea how I can populate the second array. I've tried a load of aproaches but with no joy. The countryData array stays empty.

```
function filterFromGroupChanged(value){
    var customerData = $.grep(arrayCustomers, function (customer, i) { return arrayCustomers.Group === value; });
    refreshCustomers(customerData); // function to refresh a customer selectbox

    var countryData = $.grep(arrayCountries , function (country, i) {
            return $.grep(customerData, function (customer, i) { customer.Country=== country.Code; }).length > 0;
        });
        refreshCountries(countryData); // function to refresh a country select box
}
```

The jQuery grep returns an array, so if I test the length of it I should be able to return a true or false to satisfy the first grep. But it stays empty.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I'm retarded. After posting, I looked at my code again and saw the missing return. (below in CAPS to make it better detectable for sharing here)

```
function filterFromGroupChanged(value){
    var customerData = $.grep(arrayCustomers, function (customer, i) { return arrayCustomers.Group === value; });
    refreshCustomers(customerData); // function to refresh a customer selectbox

    var countryData = $.grep(arrayCountries , function (country, i) {
            return $.grep(customerData, function (customer, i) { RETURN customer.Country=== country.Code; }).length > 0;
        });
        refreshCountries(countryData); // function to refresh a country select box
}
```